# Encrypted code in an ASP file

Tags: encryption, asp-classic

I am working on code that was originally written by a vendor that has gone out of business. It is a classic ASP site and a lot of the server side code looks like the following.  I'm wondering if there is a way to decrypt/unscramble it.

```
<%#@~^EgAAAA==@#@&P~,PxN,k6@#@&1AIAAA==^#~@%>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do your files begin with

```
<%@ LANGUAGE = VBScript.Encode %>
```

I've inherited files like that before and I decoded them with this

http://virtualconspiracy.com/content/scrdec/usage

Comment: I tried that tool but it didn't seem to work but it pointed me in the right direction.  The following link has an online tool that did the trick.  Thanks for your help.  http://www.greymagic.com/security/tools/decoder/decoder.asp

Comment: Both links are dead.

Comment: It happens.  In these situations WebArchive is your friend.
https://web.archive.org/web/20140214175353/http://www.virtualconspiracy.com:80/content/scrdec/download

Comment: Tried the srcdec tool and it didn't work on my encrypted ASP file.

Mine start with `<%@ LANGUAGE = VBScript.Encrypt %>`

Comment: @JosephQuinn  It works for me.  If you use the command line scrdec18 inputfile.asp outputfile.asp then you should find a file called outputfile.asp where the encrypted stuff is replaced with readable VBScript.  It leaves the "Language = VBScript.Encrypt" declaration at the top. which you should change to just "language = "VBScript" and it might leave a couple or encrypted lines at the top which you can usually safely delete.  It also tends to give you loads of whitespace, but the bottom line is that you should be left with a usable .asp file.

Answer (score 0):

UUDECODE & UUENCODE are you friends here.