# Classic ASP Decoding

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, encoder

I Found the following code in a 5 year old classic asp application which is working with an IVRS system and its stopped working for some reason.  Help needed to Decode this.

```
 <%@ LANGUAGE = VBScript.Encode %><script language=jscript runat=server>EiDmq='UrFwSPhHbZVbtLcVOBtOO#@~^IOembLVVUZsBJkyxQUX'</script><%'#@~^OjAAAA==%><%#@~^GgAAAA==^kIj}'rt4xrK\4}n.fAZu24w5rkggAAA==^#~@'gfwCFuX#@~^iaPtwU==sxOZqHrcHO%><%'#@~^BrAAAA==%><%#@~^QAAAAA==p}Ih{Jbrj9W}61}V;|bs4B}Lr\Pt923S3z1}lXAJ+}2&VdnI\WN3rU}r![:0%:rihYAAA==^#~@%><%'#@~^aNAAAA==%><%#@~^EgAAAA==P!/6U'rNM6r75+;;LJJgYAAA==^#~@'vInn>OQoO#@~^OlXjOO==Doleyv>WnQWS%><%'#@~^PfAAAA==%><%#@~^CwAAAA==h.DWT3X'lGGAQAAA==^#~@%><%'#@~^MRAAAA==%><%#@~^9wcAAA==@#@&BG   PDDKD,.+kEh+,xnaD@#@&Ed+DPW(%C/a+MDGDxdD-+M MYsCkY+..KDc#@#@&@#@&[b:,mW  xB~Dk~~DkFS~M/ B~Dk&~,.dcBPM/X~~.kvSPMd0KWOnM@#@&[rsP/W UUY.,@#@&BZKx   jYMPxPrf.r7+D{`HH?pd~6f~Z,& *q~GDr\.8pPj3".2]x^W^l^4K/OpPGbKzAzj2{m[DpPi(G'DKGYpPnzjj}IG'O+snkWWYp~rhK(6g'&E@#@&@#@&/O,mG    x,'PU+M-+MR/DlOnK4L^YvJbG69AcZKxU+^ObWUJ*@#@&@#@&v&JOOR7t/d;^~;WU +1YkKx,jYMkUoiORRJz@#@&vmKxxc62+    P{PEn.G7k[+Mx?5S6JAfA qpnC/kAKD[{YV+kW6Oih+./b/O~U+m!.kDXP&UWW{KMEniidD~qGx/mi(UbYkCs,ZCYmsKox^WTo+MiGCYmPjW!D^n{.r;Rn;-?5J3(hIA?jJ@#@&EmGx    ra+U~{PJK.K\rN.{?}drd2f~R8Inm/dhKD[xklihnDkk/D~j+1EMkOX~( 0G':.EiidDP(9{/Ci&UbYrmV,ZlDl^Go{Zo?|?n.7+Dp9lDlPUG;D1+{.(I3j_O92UFOqGE@#@&BmGU   R6wU,'~rnMW\bN.'UpJrd29$cFihC/khWM[xYV/G0OIh+./bdY,?n^!DkOz,qU0Kx:D;i`/+MP&9'klIq  kOrmVP;CYmVWTx/sU{U+.\n.pfCYm~?KE.^'H)H}9RoKhFwt?UpSy!Z0J@#@&vmKxU Kw+    ~JhDW7r[+M'UpJrJ3GA FpKlk/AGMN'2Ck/q 2Ih+.kkkYPU+1;DbYzP&xWG{KD!ni`/+M~(f{/mi(xrOblsP;CYmVGL{ZHjIGlOl,jKE.1+{f2j2d6nt2HK8OK/'?pd3(hI2UjE@#@&mKxUR62x~Jh.W7k[nM'?}J}S3f~ 8iKm/khWMN{AkaDG@$8 f*pn+MdkkYPUn^EMkDX~qUWK'PD!ni`/n.,qfxdmi(xbObls,ZmYl^WTxZGImZ"HI9mYl,jW!Dmx  qgOyF{K{62Zj%nE@#@&@#@&vJzORR,Hz?5J,ZG  xmYbW  ~?DDrxTPRR zz@#@&B1Wx    6wx,'~J9.b\nD{`HH?}J,rf$/,* F,9Mk-D)i?D7nD{(1 fpB_(z]"fiGCOl(lk+xVGLT+.i`d+M'.GKYiKCk/AWM[{Yn^+kW0Dir@#@&EmGx    R62xP{~JGDk7n.'PHH?}S~6GA/P2 *8P9.b\+.Np?nD7nM'    &1 f(xCqpb"]fpfCOm4lkn'^WoTn.i`/DxDGGDiKlkdhKD[xD+VndK0Oir@#@&B^Kx    Rra+    ~',J9Db\n.{ HHjpdPrG$/P2RlF~f.r7+.8pj+M\n.{VW^C^tG/DIGlOm4m/+{VKLoDIjk+.xMWWDInm//SG.N{YVn/GWDiE@#@&@#@&k+O~M/dx~U+.\.cZ.lD+W(L^Y,`EbGr9$cI+1GD9/+DEb@#@&/Y~Ddq,'~?.\D /M+lOnK4%+1O,`Ezf}fAcI^WMNd+DJb@#@&/+D~Dk P{~j+M\D Z.nmYnW(%+1Y~crbf69~R]+1GMNdYr#@#@&/OPM/fP{PjnM\+M ZM+lDnG4N+1Y~`E)Gr9Ac]+1W.[k+YEb@#@&d+D~M/*,',?+M\.R;DnlD+G8N+mD~`rbf}9$R"+1W.NdnDJb@#@&d+DP.dlP'~jD-+M ;DnmYW4N+1OPvJ)f}f$ "+mK.Nk+Yrb@#@&k+DP./~{Pj+M-+MR/.lYnG(LnmD~vJ)GrGAR"+1GD9/nYr#@#@&k+Y,./6WWDn.P{PU+.\n.cZ.+mO+K4%n1YPcEzf6f~ "+^KD9/+DJ*@#@&@#@&[ksPG8NlNKa@#@&/+D~G4Nl9WaPx~k+.\.R;DnCD+r8%mOPvEzf6oR1lYmVKLJ*@#@&W(LC[K6Rz^Yb\+;GUxmDkGx~x,mGx   @#@&pogCAA==^#~@%>
```

These weird values also set in the forms as well.

```
<input type="text" class="input" id="txtname" name="txtname" value="<%=#@~^DQAAAA==~1Wha/Mmxm:~2AQAAA==^#~@%>" />
```

Tried [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252520/encrypted-code-in-an-asp-file) and [this](https://github.com/sstraw/scrdec), but no use. may be I am doing it all wrong. Please help

Comment: this looks like a hacker-inserted snip, are you sure it's legit?

Comment: I think its more of a licensing trick or something..it is an offline application (running on local network)

Comment: Did you run scrdec18.exe on the entire file.  I just tried it on your snippet of code and got the message 'Error: premature end of file'

Comment: `VBScript.Encode` is a crude form of encoder for VBScript, it’s not a hacker script or anything. It’s simple to decode using the program already linked in the question.

Comment: @user692942 is right. The thing is to decode strings between with `#@~^` and `^#~@` and remove the `<%` and `%>` before decoding.