# Missing VBScript.Encrypt on Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, asp-classic

I'm in the process of trying to migrate a really old web application to a new Windows Server 2019 box. The old application is coded in ASP and uses

`<%@ LANGUAGE = VBScript.Encrypt %>`

As the language option for the ASP scripts.

I'm trying to run the migrated scripts on the new server and I'm getting errors:

```
Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0129'

Unknown scripting language

/Default.asp, line 1

The scripting language 'VBScript.Encrypt' is not found on the server.
```

Edit: The ProgID is not installed in the Registry. I have no idea how it's being loaded on the server. It also isn't an ISAPI filter. The application continues to run correctly on the Windows 2008 server.

Edit 2: Tried to decode the file using `scrdec18.exe` but to no avail. The program works on `VBScript.Encode` and not `VBScript.Encrypt`

Edit 3: To check further, I added a new ASP page to the loaded server with the following content:

```
<%
Dim objComponent
On Error Resume Next

' Try to create a COM object
Set objComponent = Server.CreateObject("VBScript.Encrypt")

' Check if the object was created
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Response.Write("COM Component is available.")
Else
    Response.Write("COM Component is not available.")
End If

Set objComponent = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
%>
```

The result is the COM component is not available.

However, the rest of the website encoded with `VBScript.Encrypt` still functions.

Comment: The VBScript.Encrypt directive in ASP is non-standard. It's not something that is inherently part of classic ASP or VBScript. It is likely that on the old server, there was a third-party component installed that provided this functionality to interpret and run encrypted VBScript. Find out which component or software was used on the old server to enable VBScript encryption. This could be a third-party COM component or an ISAPI filter installed on the server. install it on the new Windows Server 2019 box. Make sure to register any COM components using regsvr32 if needed.

Comment: Any ideas on where to find the component?

Comment: If you still have access to the old server, inspect it for installed programs, COM components, and ISAPI filters that might be related to VBScript.Encrypt.

Comment: I still have access to the server and did a search over the registry for related components. No luck with them being listed there. Any other thoughts on how I can search for the component?

Comment: Did you check the ISAPI filters in IIS like Joseph recommended?

Comment: Maybe you could decrypt your files.  

See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252520/encrypted-code-in-an-asp-file/23254727#23254727

Comment: To locate files of encrypting program on the old server see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30242444/893670). The PROGID you should be looking for is `VBScript.Encrypt`.

Comment: I'm not too sure I want to go the route of decrypting the files. This vendor is still active (but annoying to work with), so I don't want Legal issues with them.

Comment: The ProgID is not installed in the registry nor is it found while looking up ISAPI filters.